# SQL Grammar exception when switching from MySQL to Hypersonic in Memory DB

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to run tests for my application, but without using the production database and using a Hypersonic in Memory instead.

The problem I'm having is that after finally getting it to use the applicationContext.xml and persistence.xml files that I wanted it to use, I'm getting the following errors for tests linked to the CatalogItem class.

The problem is that I've been told specifically that I shouldn't need to modify anything in the classes itself as they run just fine with MySQL. I'm hoping the issue is with my .xml files.

test-persistence.xml

```
<!-- Classes declaration omitted -->
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

<properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
</properties>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <!-- FOR UNIT TESTING ONLY -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/test-database.properties"/>

    <bean id="externalProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
       <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound"><value>true</value></property>
       <property name="locations">
          <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/conf/configuration.properties</value>
          </list>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mms.pone.portal">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

     <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="1" />

        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/test-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

database.properties:

```
########################################################
#                                                      #
#  This configuration is used for unit-testing only.   #
#                                                      #
########################################################
# Hypersonic
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

database.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:file\:c\:/Project

database.username=sa
database.password=
```

And the stacktrace I get when running mvn

```
Tests in error:
  testDeleteAsset(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.AssetIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.mms.pone.portal.domain.Asset#64]; nested exception is ja
vax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.mms.pone.portal.domain.Asset#64]
  testFindCatalogItem(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceExc
eption: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testCountAllCatalogItems(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.Persisten
ceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testFindAllCatalogItems(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.Persistenc
eException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testFindCatalogItemEntries(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.Persist
enceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testUpdateCatalogItemUpdate(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.Persis
tenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testSaveCatalogItem(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceExc
eption: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testDeleteCatalogItem(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceE
xception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
  testFlush(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest): org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: or
g.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

log output for the CatalogItemIntegrationTest:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.024 sec <<< FAILURE!
testFlush(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:326)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.findCatalogItemEntries_aroundBody6(CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:31)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem$findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem.findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItem.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem$findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.service.CatalogItemServiceImpl_Roo_Service.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_service_CatalogItemServiceImpl_Roo_Service$com_mms_pone_portal_service_CatalogItemServiceImpl$findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItemServiceImpl_Roo_Service.aj:35)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.service.CatalogItemServiceImpl.findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItemServiceImpl.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$init(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:159)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand.init(CatalogItemDataOnDemand.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$init(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$getRandomCatalogItem(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:146)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand.getRandomCatalogItem(CatalogItemDataOnDemand.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$getRandomCatalogItem(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemIntegrationTest$testFlush(CatalogItemIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:74)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest.testFlush(CatalogItemIntegrationTest.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [select top ? catalogite0_.id as id6_, catalogite0_.active as active6_, catalogite0_.category_id as category14_6_, catalogite0_.deliveryTime as delivery3_6_, catalogite0_.descriptionLong as descript4_6_, catalogite0_.descriptionShort as descript5_6_, catalogite0_.ean as ean6_, catalogite0_.externalFormId as external7_6_, catalogite0_.manufacturer_id as manufac15_6_, catalogite0_.name as name6_, catalogite0_.remarks as remarks6_, catalogite0_.sapMatNr as sapMatNr6_, catalogite0_.supplierAid as supplie11_6_, catalogite0_.supplier_catalog_id as supplier16_6_, catalogite0_.type as type6_, catalogite0_.version as version6_ from CatalogItem catalogite0_]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    ... 56 more
testFindCatalogItem(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:326)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.findCatalogItemEntries_aroundBody6(CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:31)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem$findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem.findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItem.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItem$findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItem_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.service.CatalogItemServiceImpl_Roo_Service.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_service_CatalogItemServiceImpl_Roo_Service$com_mms_pone_portal_service_CatalogItemServiceImpl$findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItemServiceImpl_Roo_Service.aj:35)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.service.CatalogItemServiceImpl.findCatalogItemEntries(CatalogItemServiceImpl.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$init(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:159)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand.init(CatalogItemDataOnDemand.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$init(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethod$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$getRandomCatalogItem(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:146)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand.getRandomCatalogItem(CatalogItemDataOnDemand.java:1)
    at com.mms.pone.portal.domain.CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand$com_mms_pone_portal_domain_CatalogItemDataOnDemand$getRandomCatalogItem(CatalogItemDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj)
```

Comment: What is your database URL and driver class name? Can you add the code of the test class and the entity in question? Can you enable SQL logging (in your persistence.xml) and add the log output to your question?

Comment: Added the database-properties to my question. The log output is considerably long, I'll add it for the CatalogItem first test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not what I was looking for initially, the tests ran perfectly after switching to H2-IN-MEMORY...

Answer (score 1):

The table "CatalogItem" was not found:

```
Table not found in statement [select top ? [...] from CatalogItem catalogite0_]
```

So maybe your setting of the property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is not correct. You could try "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update", maybe it helps. Or you could use dbmaintain - http://dbmaintain.org/overview.html - instead of "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto". It is safer and more flexible anyway.

If this does not help, try to enable SQL logging and review the generated SQL statements. Add the following properties to your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> 
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
```

**Edit** It might also help if you inspect your HSQL database with a tool like Squirrel: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ You can check if all tables are created correctly using it.

Comment: Update yields the same result with those particular 9 tests failing and the others running just fine. Also, I have to use hibernate...

Comment: Ok. Have you tried SQL logging? Also, you can still use hibernate, even if you use dbmaintain - It only creates and updates your database schema.

Comment: Thanks for the input...I'll keep trying stuff. Thing is I'm also a beginner in Spring + Maven + Hibernate which makes it a bit trickier.